# Is there a built in functionality in Windows.Forms or WPF for shortcut chains (like in VS Ctrl + K, C)

Tags: .net

There is standard functionality for shortcuts which are Modifiers + Key, which is quite easy to implement, but is there a way to easely (using standard libraries) implement shortcuts like Ctrl + K, C (Holding Ctrl press K and then C). Something like keyboard gestures, but I haven't found.

Comment: I would equally appreciate an answer even if it's not possible with default .Net functionality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, nothing built-in. However, for WPF, Kent Boogaart recently had a very nice blog post with a [solution](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/03/multikeygesture.html).